# Conversion of surface areas in metric system

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, unit-of-measure

I know i just make this question but this time im asking how to express correctly my doubt. Thanks for being patient.

---

Are there an explanation for this current issue?:
is 1000m2 = 1km2 (Area of a square)?
(l) lenght x (w) width = (Area of a square)2 
if
10m x 100m = 1000m2 (1km2)
then
100m2 = 10m x 10m
1m2 = 10cm x 10cm
1cm2 = 3.33ml x 3.33333...ml

---

Or
Every time i said a "Square meter, kilometre or centimetre" means:

---

1m2 = 1m x 1m
1cm2 = 1cm x 1cm
1km2 = 1 km x 1 km

Comment: Please do not replace the question, especially *after* answers have been posted. Rolled back.

Comment: Ok. i can't deleted it doesnt allow me.

Answer (score 1):

$1000 \rm{m}^2\ne 1 \rm{km}^2$.

In fact $1\rm{km}^2=1\rm{km}\cdot 1\rm{km}=1000\rm{m}\cdot 1000\rm{m}=1,000,000\rm{m}^2$

Comment: <3 thanks for the answer